# Javascript copy to clipboard when you don't know the ID

Tags: javascript

I have a table with various columns, and I want the user to be able to copy text in a cell by clicking on it. This is dynamic content, so I don't know what the ID or class will be at the time.

This works for me, but it will obviously not work because of `getElementById`. How could I do it so the copy works for the cell the use clicks on?

```
function copyAddress() {
    /* Get the text field */
    var copyText = document.getElementById("address");

    /* Select the text field */
    copyText.select();
    copyText.setSelectionRange(0, 99999); /* For mobile devices */

    /* Copy the text inside the text field */
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(copyText.value);
}
```

Comment: How can you tell when a user clicks on a cell?

Comment: I was doing it with `<div onclick="copyAddress()">`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi if you wanted to copy the text on dynamic table you'll need to select the element first. since you're unsure if what's the class/id you should just select the html element

let's say i have this table and i wanted to select all inside text inside td

```
  <table >
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

you could do on javascript is

let content = document.querySelectorAll('table tr td'); // All td will be selected and will be added to NodeList

after that you'll want to convert that nodelist into array.

let contentArr = Array.from(content) // you can use Array.from

then just loop through all the elements you have and for each one add an event listener (click) then get the innerText and copy it to the clipboard. you can check it here [Hope it helps](https://codepen.io/markmendozadev/pen/abEGQzP)

```
contentArr.forEach((element) => {
  element.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    let copyText = e.target.innerText
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(copyText);
  });
});
```

---

EDIT: i saw on one of comments that this is how you detect the click

if that's the case is the onclick function adding automatically on the div you wanted to be selected? if yes

what you can do is

`<div onclick="copyAddress(this)">` **add this keyword inside your function**

now what you can do on javascript is

```
function copyAddress(e) {
 navigator.clipboard.writeText(e.innerText); // the e is the current element and just get the innerText and copy it to clipboard.
}
```

---

EDIT:

if this is your format

```
<div onclick="copyAddress(this)"><textarea>text to copy</textarea></div>
```

```
function copyAddress(e) {
  const copyText = e.firstChild;
  copyText.select();
  copyText.setSelectionRange(0, 99999);
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(copyText.value);

}
```

Comment: Ok that's great - works pretty well! Now if I want to do it this way: `<div onclick="copyAddress(this)"><textarea>Text to copy</textarea>` how could I target that? In my head `navigator.clipboard.writeText(e.textArea.value); ` but that obviously doesn't work

Comment: Hi if that's the case you can select the firstChild
inside your function you can add back your code and just select the first child as value.

          const copyText = e.firstChild;
          copyText.select();
          copyText.setSelectionRange(0, 99999);

          navigator.clipboard.writeText(copyText.value);

Comment: i edited my answer so it will be readable for you

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean the class name would be different? If so, you could put the dynamic class inside of a static div that won't change. That might work.

```js
function copyAddress() {
  let childItem = document.getElementById("parentDivName").firstElementChild;

  /* Obviously you would tweak this to work for you, this is just an idea */
  
}
```

Comment: Thanks - same issue sadly. It's because there's about 50 rows per page and clicking to copy and of them will just find the first div in the first row...